# Android Debug Bridge won't stop

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, adb, madbee

I have an WinForm app built using Xamarin on VS2015 who uses ADB to detect an Android device connection. It works fine, but when I close the software, the ADB thread won't stop even if there is a Stop in the Form_Closing event, so the program stays in memory forever. In VS debugger, the culprit threads shows "Device List Monitor", the name of the thread that still running. How can I fix this?

Here's the code:

```
AndroidDebugBridge m_ADB;

In the Form_Load:
string S = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
S = S + "\adb.exe";
m_ADB = AndroidDebugBridge.CreateBridge(S, true);
m_ADB.DeviceConnected += this.MADB_DeviceConnected;
m_ADB.DeviceDisconnected += this.MADB_DeviceDisconnected; ;
m_ADB.Start();
```

In the Form_Closing:

```
m_ADB.Stop();
m_ADB = null;
```

thanks for your time and help

Answer (score 0):

`MADB.Stop()` closes the `adb` *client* connection. The other process you see is `adb` *server*. To kill that you need to use `MADB.StopAdb()`

Comment: there is no StopAdb() function in the AndroidDebugBridge lib ??